# Not in outer par mode...How can I know which mode am I in?

Tags: floats, footnotes

I got this error message "not in outer par mode" for `\begin{figure}` or `\begin{table}` after I use `\footnote`.

The `\footnote` is correct.

Presumably a package I am using has problem.

Is there any way to know where this issue came from?

```
\documentclass[14pt,fleqn,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{siam} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} 
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol,enumerate}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[avantgarde]{quotchap} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[heightrounded,footskip=50pt,headheight=30pt,head=17pt,headsep=20pt,twoside,a4paper,
bindingoffset=1.4 cm,left=1.4cm,right=1.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{insert}{tbh}{lop}
\floatname{insert}{insert}
\newfloat{program}{tbhp}{lop}
\floatname{program}{Program}
\begin{document}
\footnote{test}
\begin{insert}[tb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, angle=0]{insertion}
\end{insert}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You want to display an image inside a `\footnote`? Then don't but the image inside a `figure` environment. If you want a caption as part of a complete figure, then you need to not let the `figure` float. For this add `\usepackage{float}` to your preamble and use the `[H]` float specifier.

Comment: no!! I am not using figure or table inside footnote. It is after the footnote is closed.

Comment: @latra: Okay, so show us the offending code that allows us to replicate the behaviour.

Comment: It is quite long and difficult to reduce to a minimum example...At this moment I only know whereever I move the \footnote the \begin{figure} afterwards has problem, which is not occured in my other TeX compilation.

Comment: We really can't be much help with code which causes the problem. You're telling us your code is correct, but you get an error. What can we say? Either you have a dud TeX which gives errors from correct code or you are mistaken about its correctness. I don't really know what you mean about moving the footnote, though.  What if you don't move it? Where are you moving it from and to?

Comment: @latra TeX is a very singular language, in the sense that its behavior can be changed beyond recognition. So without the code that causes the issue, it is quite hard (and sometimes impossible) to say what's the problem. My **guess** is that you try to move the `\footnote` after the `\end{figure}` and change it to `\footnotetext`. Then, in the place where the footnote was, you put only a `\footnotemark`. But to tell you something certain we would have to see some of your code.

Comment: I move the following code \footnote{...} \begin{figure} ...\end{figure}  to the very beginning of my file.....it still happen....I can only think some package I use cause the issue. But I don't know how can I display which mode am I in?

Comment: Here is the code, although not minimum:

Comment: I added the code.....

Comment: Try `{}\footnote{test}`

Comment: Please don't invalidate existing answers with your edits.

Answer (score 6):

`\insert` is a TeX primitive. Therefore, defining an `insert` float, redefines `\insert` (and `\endinsert`) which is the cause of your issue.

To resolve it, rather define the float as `insertion`:

```
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{insertion}{tbh}{lop}
\floatname{insertion}{insert}

%...

\begin{insertion}
  %...
\end{insertion}
```

Comment: Many thanks. So...I violate the keyword usage?

Comment: @latra the float package `\newfloat` command really should have warned you about that it is worth contacting the author and asking for the package to add a check that `\newfloat` really is defining a new name.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Dear author... could you add a check that `\newfloat` really is defining a new name? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can fix `float.sty` so it warns you about a risky definition. Since `\begin{whatever}` requires `\whatever` to be defined. In your case the package, as it stands, will *redefine* `\insert` and this is a very bad thing to do, because `\insert` is a primitive (which is used in the context of floats, but this is not really relevant, although it's the reason for the puzzling error message).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{float}

% fix \newfloat
\makeatletter
\let\@float@newfloat\newfloat
\renewcommand{\newfloat}[3]{%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname #1\endcsname{%
    \@float@newfloat{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
% end of fix

\newfloat{insert}{tbh}{lop}
\floatname{insert}{insert}
\newfloat{program}{tbhp}{lop}
\floatname{program}{Program}
\begin{document}
\footnote{test}
\begin{insert}[tb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, angle=0]{insertion}
\end{insert}
\end{document}
```

With this fix you'd get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \insert already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.16 \newfloat{insert}{tbh}{lop}
```

that will make clear you cannot define a float type named `insert`. Now choose a different name.

I recommend to use the more modern `newfloat` package, if you don't need the `\restylefloat` feature.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  filext=lop,
  listname={List of Inserts},
  name=Insert,
  placement=htbp,
]{insertion}

\begin{document}
\footnote{test}

\begin{insertion}[tbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, angle=0]{insertion}
\end{insertion}

\end{document}
```

This package would by default warn if the chosen environment name is already taken.

Comment: but wouldn't *any* float within a footnote be a problem?

Comment: @barbarabeeton My comment to the OP was based on a guess about the problem, before a MWE was added. It turns out that the footnote just triggered a weird error, because `\insert` got redefined.

Comment: @egreg thanks for the fix code. A naive question: why do you need a % after the end of each line?